# How to reset an object with a click jquery

Tags: jquery, object

I have the following object and what I want to do is set the value of page in that object to another value or reset it when the user clicks li.product, as it activates pagination with the list.js plugin. How could I do this? Thanks!

```
var options = {
        valueNames: ['packageid', 'categoryid',  'meta-package', 'meta-category', 'meta-brand', 'meta-company', 'meta-country'],
        page:24,
        plugins: [
            [ 'paging', {
                name: "duja",
                pagingClass: "bottomPaging",
                innerWindow: 1,
                outerWindow: 2
            } ]
        ]
    };


$('li.product').live("click",function() {
        displayItem($(this));
        $('.single').fadeIn();
        return false;
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set something like this, `options.page = 0;`

If you want to set everything to null then `options = {};`

```
$('li.product').on("click",function() {
        displayItem($(this));
        $('.single').fadeIn();
        options.page = 0;
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: Be careful with `live`, it is deprecated.